# How do I stop "Maintain QT" from appearing on Windows Boot?

Tags: qt

Everytime I restart Windows, the QT creator shows up:

[image]

Also I noticed this is running from this `Start Menu/Programs/Startup/` folder, I don't know why this is there:

[image]

Finally, I noticed that when I search for "QT" on the start menu, I can't find the application.

How do I stop "Maintain QT" from appearing on Windows Boot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We cannot read the minds of developers. Delete it from the startup folder if it bothers you.

Comment: There is also a Startup tab in Windows 10/11 Task Manager.

Comment: Ok, I thought I was clear on what I'm asking, I changed the question to make it very explicit